# open many webpages with phantomjs

Tags: javascript, phantomjs, javascript-objects

I use phantomjs to get some data from some websites that update automatically every second with ajax. These websites update for 3 hours, so we need to get some data from them every second for that amount of time.
I defined an object for opening each webpage like this:

```
function myobj(nemad, url) {
    this.url = url;
    this.nemad = nemad;
    var me = this;
    nemad = require('webpage').create();
    nemad.open(url);
    this.myans = function() {
        var ua = nemad.evaluate(function() {

            return document.getElementById("MainContent");
        });
        return ua;
    }
}
```

We have an array that has about 200 urls for those webpages (`urls =[...];`). For opening the pages we first define a new object for each url and store that in an array like below:

```
var arr=[];
for ( i=0;i<urls.length;i++) {

    arr.push(new stocks(nemads[i], urls[i]));
}
```

When all of the webpages opened successfully we need to call the `myobj.myans();` function for each webpage to get the data.

```
setInterval(function() {
    var result = [];
    for (i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {

        result.push(arr[i].myval());

    }

    console.log("Result => " + result );

}, 1000);
```

So we have some problem :

1. After opening about 40 webpages phantomjs crashes, I know we should use `webpage.close()` for release of the memory, but we must open each webpage for a long time (3hr) and receiving data every second.
2. The most important problem is, when we open for example 40 pages the memory usage increases every second. Each page size is 100kb so 40 pages memory usage is about 4 MB, but every second memory usage increases up to 1GB for about 10min and phantomjs crashes after that.

What is the wrong?

Comment: Might need an architectural change; What do you think about spawning 200 phantomjs instances, probably to a cluster. Each instance then opens one page and monitors it for your period.

Comment: it means that we should copy 200 phantomjs and open a webpage in each phantomjs ?

Comment: seams can do that easier